# Is it reasonable to have properties file while having Javaconfig classes in spring projects?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I encountered handful of guides to creating spring data jpa projects and people configured persistence layer using properties file and javaconfig both. If we one uses javaconfig why would they even bother to create another properties file to include configurations? If one strategy is used(i.e. JavaConfig) to configure project , what is the use of the other (i.e. properties file) strategy? Do I have a misunderstanding as to how to configure projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaConfig](http://javaconfig.sourceforge.net/gettingstarted.html) was mostly used for old version of `Java` or legacy projects. It is a helper library used to avoid the boiler plate needed to write a code to open the `properties` file and map the values directly to a class that can represent your properties in memory.

With `JavaConfig` your code will looks like [this](http://javaconfig.sourceforge.net/gettingstarted.html) and without it, your code will look like [this](https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

> If one strategy is used(i.e. JavaConfig) to configure project , what
> is the use of the other (i.e. properties file) strategy? Do I have a
> misunderstanding as to how to configure projects?

`Properties` file, is the standard used in `Java` to store external configuration values. It is a **key/value** file, example: **application.properties** or **application.yml** are used in modern framework such as `Spring`, that offer a [simple](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) way to manage your properties file.